# How do I generate an impulse in Pspice?

Tags: pspice

I want to generate a narrow pulse of very small duration. How can I implement it using PWL function. Or is there any other method for this.

Comment: Go back to your previous question and read the first comment. It tells you what to do.

Comment: Differentiate a unit step.

Comment: @Chu I don't think it is possible to make a true "unit step" in SPICE any more than it is possible to make a true impulse.